# I want to use it as a UIButton when I tap UITextField

Tags: uitextfield, tvos

I created a custom keyboard screen on tvOS.
If possible, tap on UITextField as it is, I want to transition to the custom keyboard view.
But tapping the UITextField always displays the system keyboard.
What should I do now?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make the view controller implement this delegate: **UITextFieldDelegate**

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    // ...
    yourTextField.delegate = self
    // ...
}
```

2) Return **false** in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`, so the text field doesn't respond and the keyboard doesn't open. Instead, open yours or do whatever you want.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // HERE, open your keyboard or do whatever you want
    return false
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was able to display my keyboard!

Answer (score 0):

```
textField.inputView = UIView()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!I tried it. But it crashed.That's because it is tvos.*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSLayoutConstraint for <UIView: 0x7fd99fd13d70; frame = (0 0; 1920 1080); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000df4840>>: A multiplier of 0 or a nil second item together with a location for the first attribute creates an illegal constraint of a location equal to a constant. Location attributes must be specified in pairs.'

Comment: @flyoo - you should update your question with these informations

Comment: @flyoo create one UIView programmatically and set gave constraint and then after set in inputview. I think it working

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate { }
```

First set your delegate for textfield`textField.delegate = self`, Then

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(gettextFieldFunction), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
}
```